# Consulta de Inner Join a una misma tabla

Tags: php, html, mysql, phalcon

de antemano gracias :)

Tengo una pequeña pregunta, debo tomar los datos de un id que se encuentra en la tabla usando phalcon con mvc.

La cuestión es esta, mi tabla es la siguiente:

```
|-----------|-----------|----------|--------------|----------------|
| idusuario | nombre    | apellido | clase        | idpatrocinador |
|-----------|-----------|----------|--------------|----------------|  
| 20065     | María     | Perez    | distribuidor | **20012**      |
|-----------|-----------|----------|--------------|----------------|
| **20012** | Christian | Ramirez  | consumidor   | 20015          |
|-----------|-----------|----------|--------------|----------------|
```

Si notan, Christian es el patrocinador de María y lo que yo deseo es mostrar los datos de Christian en la vista en vez de su id.

En mi controlador tengo esto:

```
<?php
class PruebaController extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Controller
{
public function pruebaAction()
{
}

public function indexAction()
{
    //Primera consulta general
    $usuarios = Usuario::find();
    $this->view->usuarios = $usuarios;

    //Segunda consulta para patrocinadores
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usuario INNER JOIN usuario ON usuario.idusuario=usuario.idpatrocinador";
    $sentencia = $this->db->prepare($query);
    $sentencia->execute();
    $row = $sentencia->fetch();
    $this->view->row = $row;

}
}
```

Y en la vista esta es mi tabla en la vista:

```
<table class="table table-striped  table-bordered table-hover"  
 id="enviar_usuario">
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th scope="col">#</th>
  <th scope="col">Nombre completo</th>
  <th scope="col">Clase</th>
  <th scope="col">Patrocinador</th>
  <th scope="col">Acción</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <?php 
    foreach($usuarios as $user)
    {
?>
<tr>
  <th><?php echo $user->idusuario ?></th>
  <td><?php echo $user->nombre . ' ' . $user->apellido; ?></td>
  <td><span class='badge badge-info'><?php echo $user->clase ?></span>";      
  </td>
<td> <!-- Aqui debe ir los datos del patrocinador. Su nombre completo, id y clasesph -->
</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="id_usuario" onclick="enviarid('<?php echo $user->idusuario; ?>')" ><i class="icon-pencil5 position-left"></i>
    Editar</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php 
    }
?>
```

Agradecería mucho a quienes pudieran ayudarme

Comment: Osea que tanto los datos del usuario como patrocinador están en la misma tabla?

Comment: Así es, ambos id representan lo mismo

Comment: Eso es incorrecto, redundancia de información deberían ser dos tablas una de usuarios y otra de patrocinadores

Comment: Sí, pero así lo desea el jefe jaja

Comment: Bueno en cuanto pueda te posteo cómo hacerlo pero eso está mal diseñado y no sirve como tal

Comment: Muchas gracias por su tiempo. Yo había creado la tabla de patrocinadores pero él no lo quería así.

Comment: @ShadowPaz no veo porque deberían ser dos tablas, si deseo tener una estructura de arbol puedo tener todo en una misma tabla y relacionarlo con un parent_id, en este caso idpatrocinador

Comment: Cierto solo fue mi opinión

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas hacer una segunda consulta para obtener los patrocinadores. Puedes generar ahi mismo el arreglo de patrocinadores en el controlador

```
$usuarios = Usuario::find();
$patrocinadores = array();
$foreach ($usuarios as $usuario) {
    $patrocinadores[$usuario->idusuario] = $usuario;
}
$this->view->usuarios = $usuarios;
$this->view->patrocinadores = $patrocinadores;
```

en la vista, puedes realizar lo siguiente

```
    <?php 
    foreach($usuarios as $user)
    {
?>
<tr>
  <th><?php echo $user->idusuario ?></th>
  <td><?php echo $user->nombre . ' ' . $user->apellido; ?></td>
  <td><span class='badge badge-info'><?php echo $user->clase ?></span>";      
  </td>
<td> 
    <?php
    $patrocinador = $patrocinadores[$user->idpatrocinador];
    echo $patrocinador->nombre . ' ' . $patrocinador->apellido . ' ' . $patrocinador->idusuario . ' ' . $patrocinador->clase;
    ?>
</td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" id="id_usuario" onclick="enviarid('<?php echo $user->idusuario; ?>')" ><i class="icon-pencil5 position-left"></i>
    Editar</button>
  </td>
</tr>
<?php 
    }
```

Comment: No me reconoce el $usuario en la vista :( Disculpa, soy nueva en el mundo de phalcon y mvc.

Comment: donde tienes `<!-- Aqui debe ir los datos del patrocinador. Su nombre completo, id y clasesph -->`, `$usuario` se define en el ciclo for, es `$user` cierto.

Comment: ¿Y sus parámetros serían...? jajaj

Comment: A que te refieres con parámetros? Estás listando todos los usuarios y sus patrocinadores.

Comment: No te entiendo.

Comment: Perdón, déjame ser un poco más clara y disculpa mi inexperiencia. Quiero decir, los valores del for. Estoy pasando a la vista $usuarios y $patrocinadores, sin embargo quien tiene el array es $patrocinadores. Si el for  es int i = valor inicial; i <= valor final; i = i +, mi pregunta es cuál sería su inicial? es obvio que patrocinador pero no me formulo toda la idea.

Comment: tanto usuarios como patrocinadores son el mismo arreglo, solo que uno esta referenciado(sus llaves) son incrementales, y otro tiene referencias de idusuario, para poder encontrar al patrocinador. Puedes verlo haciendo `echo '<pre>';print_r($usuarios);print_r($patrocinadores);echo '</pre>';`, incluso puedes solo hacer el `foreach`sobre patrocinadores

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si ya vi que en el segundo comentario puse `for`, cuando es `foreach`.

Comment: Jaja, ya me estaba dividiendo la cabeza. Pero me funcionó, estoy muy agradecida. Te envío un beso virtual!

Answer (score 3):

El hacer un JOIN a una misma tabla se considera una relación de tipo recursiva, se resuelve mediante el uso de alias.

```
SELECT u2.*
FROM usuario u1
INNER JOIN usuario u2 ON u1.idusuario = u2.idpatrocinador
```

Tienes más información [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query).